# How do I filter a foreach loop in Razor? Preferably with JavaScript though I'm pretty sure with how MVC works it won't be possible

Tags: javascript, asp.net, search, razor, umbraco

Sorry in advance for the probably super simple question, and for my terrible programming vocabulary. Please let me know if I need to add any more info.

I have an Umbraco project I'm working on but I'm a bit new to Razor and how everything interacts with each other. I've populated a table with a foreach loop that displays my contact list, but is there anyway to create a filter with user input that would only show matching results to that input?

This is the HTML for the search bar and the populating table:

```
<!-- search bar -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="search-wrapper col">
    <input class="form-control" name="searchBox" id="searchBox" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div>
</div>
<!-- main bulk of content -->
<div>@Umbraco.Field("bodyText")</div>
<hr>
<div class="row searchResults hidden">
  <div class="wrapper col-12">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Region</th>
          <th>Number</th>
          <th>Extension</th>
          <th>Fax</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        @foreach (var doc in CurrentPage.contactList) {
        <tr>
          <td style="display:none;">@doc.reference</td>
          <td>@doc.title</td>
          <td style="display:none;">@doc.titleFull</td>
          <td>@doc.firstName</td>
          <td>@doc.lastName</td>
          <td>@doc.region</td>
          <td>@doc.number</td>
          <td>@doc.extension</td>
          <td>@doc.fax</td>
        </tr>
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Before everything was in Angular, but I wanted a simple CMS to help other members not have to rely on me for adding/removing things on the site (it's an internal website that has links and a simple contact list of people/numbers). I had it populate based on the input value after every keydown, which probably isn't the best practice but it was useful for keeping things easily editable for everyone.

Thank you in advance for reading my post.

Comment: The problem that you are stuck with is that of course your datasource is on the server side, and the filtering that you want is on the client side.  The best solution is to create a SurfaceController and call it with ajax based on your user input field. Are you working in an IDE like Visual Studio or similar, or or you just developing from within the Umbraco CMS - like in templates and partial views?

Comment: @hardba11 Hi, thanks for the response. I'm doing it mainly in Visual Studio Code, with a little bit of work in the Umbraco CMS itself. This is probably a good time to try out VS IDE more than I have already. I like your suggestion, and I'll try it out. Thank you again!

Comment: How many records are you filtering on? If not too large, you could load all the data on initial page load and then do the filtering via JavaScript.

Comment: @Alex Not a lot. Right now 3 with 9 attributes each, most likely reaching around 100 total. On my Angular project the page load was minimal so what you're suggesting is my preferred option. Where I'm having trouble is I've tried including some simple tests in my scripts file but I can't seem to get it to recognize the data. My programming vocabulary is terrible so I am unsure how to word my question into Google as well. I hope that makes sense.